# How to autoscroll on scroll event using JQuery and Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, autoscroll

I'm trying to accomplish an effect like in http://alfabank.ru

When the user scrolls, the website will dynamically autoscroll to an anchor. Is there any way to do this using JQuery and Bootstrap?

I found an event that may help me creating this effect http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onscroll.asp . Anyway, I don't know how to get the direction of the scroll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like [smooth-scroll](https://github.com/cferdinandi/smooth-scroll).

If that is too complicated for your needs there is a simpler tutorial online at [DWUser](http://www.dwuser.com/education/content/quick-guide-adding-smooth-scrolling-to-your-webpages/), which talks you through it.